# I want to do the Spark tutorial in an SBT project, what libraries do I need to install?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, sbt

I want to do the Apache Spark [quick-start tutorial](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html). I'd like to use a Scala worksheet in IntelliJ for each of the examples.

What do I need to add to my SBT configuration in order to make this work? Currently, I have:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0"
```

But that's not sufficient to get everything working. What else do I need to install to get everything working?

Comment: Why revert? Important tags were removed (sbt should be the main one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with those:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "2.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.12" % "2.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.12" % "2.4.0"
```

Comment: You don't need to add the `_2.12` part, if you use a double percent _(`%%`)_ between the **group** and the **artifact**.